# Mongoid Localized fields feature in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongoid, spring-data-mongodb

I'm looking for a MongoDB i18n implementation in Java.

In Mongoid there is a support for localized fields ([link](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/6.1/api/Mongoid/Fields/Localized.html)). By telling the field to localize, Mongoid will under the covers store the field as a hash of locale/value pairs, but normal access to it will behave like a string.

I can't find same feature in Java. You need to implement it yourself for each field of each entity.

Is there a similar feature in Java? If not, what is a standarized way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The i18n support in Mongoid is aligned with Ruby ecosystem, and Ruby on Rails in particular, not MongoDB. I am unaware of there being such a thing as a "MongoDB i18n implementation".

MongoDB *drivers* do not provide i18n functionality. Note that Mongoid is not a driver (it is a separate project that exists above the driver).

I would search for "Java i18n" in general and look for how to integrate those libraries into your application.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

As of "MongoDB i18n implementation" in Java I mean a generic conversion service between a field (String) in the entity and a set of locale/value pairs in MongoDB. Mongoid has a support for this. I was wondering if there is something like this in Java. As a matter of fact, my current implementation is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60956356/implementing-mongodb-i18n-with-spring-data)